# Creating a standalone C executable

Tags: c, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to create a standalone executable from a C file so that the libraries that I'm using don't have to be installed on the computer that I'm running the executable on.

I'm using the `libssh` and `libconfig` libraries, both of which may need to be installed on the machine I'm running the executable on.

When I run my binary on a machine that doesn't have these libraries installed, I get:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libssh.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can compile my `program.c` file so that it has the `libssh` binaries included within it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246923/c-compile-with-dependencies-included

Answer (score 1):

See this Link http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_linking.html about how to link the static version of the libssh. There must be similar instructions for libconfig.