# Is that anyway to update c++ packages when the project is install with `pip install -e .`?

Tags: python, c++, pip, python-wheel

I am working on a Python project that have some C++ packages in it. To make it easier to test, I used to install under developed Python packages with `pip install -e .`. It works well with pure python packages. But for the project with C++ packages in it this method won't work when the C++ code get updated. In order to it test I have to use `pip install .` to build wheel and install, which is kind of slow. Is there any solution to just build C++ packages in place to make `pip install -e .` work for such situation?

Comment: You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51903090/4596031). Also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/922060) might help find you a workaround

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ Thank you but I think they are completely different issues. I am not to handle external dependencies. The C++ packages are part of project as source code, and in order to test them I need to have a way to just recompile them without using `pip install`

Comment: usually `C/C++ libraries` use file `Makefile` and command `make` to automate process - so you could create own `Makefile` and run it. But I don't know details. Maybe `pip` uses some settings in package to run code. Maybe it display executed command when you run `pip` and you could use them in `Makefile`.